# CodeIgniter: Passing information from the Model to the Controller using result_array()

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model, controller

I have the following model that `print_r` shows `Array ( [id] => 1 [cms_name] => Content Mangement System )`  Currently in my controller I have `$data['contentMangement'] = $this->model->function` but I am unsure how to bring my above array into this.

```
function systemOptions($options)
    {   
        $this->db->select($options);

        $query = $this->db->get('options');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->row_array();

            $row['cms_name'];
        }
                print_r($row);

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: return `$row` instead of `$query->result_array()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of your options you can do this:

```
function systemOptions($options)
{   
    $this->db->select($options);

    return $this->db->get('options')->result_array();// will return empty array if there are no results

}
```

Or if you just want the first row (which is what it looks like from your question) you can do this:

```
function systemOptions($options)
{   
    $this->db->select($options);

    $result = $this->db->get('options')->result_array();

    if(!empty($result))
    {
      return $result[0];
    }else{
      return null; //or false or array(), or whatever you want
    }
}
```